# parameter b diverges when calculating gradient descent for linear regression

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I have two arrays x and y:

```
x = np.arange(-500, 500, 3)
y = 2.5*x+5
```

I want to perform a linear regression by calculating gradient descent

I implemented a gradient descent function,

```
def gradient_descent(x, y, alpha, epochs):
  w = 0.0
  b = 0.0
  n = len(x)
  for a in range(epochs):
    if a % 100 == 0: print(w,b)
    for i in range(n):
      new_w = (-2*alpha*x[i]*(y[i]-w*x[i]+b))/n
      new_b = (-2*alpha*(y[i]-w*x[i]+b))/n
      w -= new_w
      b -= new_b
  return w,b
```

Given hyperparameters alpha=0.0005 and epochs=10000, it calculates well w but when calculating b it diverges to infinity. How can I fix it?

Comment: What are the formulas you are simulating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close but you missed some parentheses in both your formulas:
Not only b would diverge to infinity like this but probably w as well (but slower).

See the missing parentheses below:

```
  new_w = (-2*alpha*x[i]*(y[i]-  (  w*x[i]+b  )  ))/n
  new_b = (-2*alpha*(y[i]-  (  w*x[i]+b  )  ))/n
```

The difference to your code is `-wx[i]+b` != `-(wx[i]+b)` because of the - sign outside of the parentheses.